# AngularJs directive watching async data

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use prettyprint with some ajax data. The problem is that when the directive is invoked, the data arem't ready, so I get undefined variable output.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fdRi2nIvVzT3Rcy2YIlK?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


$scope.result = $http.get('data.json').success(function(result){
  return result.data.dom
})

}); 


app.directive('prettyprint', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.html(prettyPrintOne(scope.result))
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `scope`'s [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) method:

```
 scope.$watch("result" , function(n,o){
      element.html(prettyPrintOne(scope.result));
 })
```

And instead of this:

```
 $scope.result = $http.get('data.json').success(function(result){
      return result.data.dom
 })
```

Use this:

```
 $http.get('data.json').success(function(result){
      $scope.result =  result.dom;
 })
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Autg0V